# Using jQuery, is is possible to watch a DOM element and report each time something is done to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm working on a site containing a confusing chain of asynchronous effects. Often, effects do/undo each other several times before stopping. I am having a very hard time following the spaghetti code.

Is it possible to set a callback to run any time a DOM element is manipulated so I can follow the chain of effects the code is applying to it?

*Edit: I am currently adding dozens of console.logs everywhere and wanted a cleaner approach.*

Comment: Can you not just use the Console to see what is going on?

Comment: In Chrome there are DOM-Breakpoints you can set.

Comment: Deprecated, but something: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Comment: When you say "asynchronous", how is that implemented?

Comment: jQuery supports asynchronous events like `$('#el').show(1000); somethingelse()`. Which splits and runs `somethingElse()` before the `show()` has *finished* running. Javascript is asynchronous by nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is *hooking* into the core jQuery functions and log the information you want. Here's some very rough code on a few functions that i've hijacked i.e hide and animate.

```
var log_for_functions = 'hide animate'.split(' '); 
$.each( log_for_functions , function(){ 
var function_name = this;
var original_function = $.fn[ original_function_name ]; // get a reference to old function name  

    $.fn[ function_name ] = function () {
        var r = original_function.apply(this, arguments); 
        console.log( function_name + ' called on element ', this );  
        return r;
    }

});
```

Now if you hide an element using jquery `$('#test').hide()` then you will get the following output.

`hide called on element  [context: #test, selector: "#test"]`

You can change this to fit your needs and even hook into other functions.

Comment: I like it. There is no need to edit existing code, I could enable this from the console when needed, and I can easily reset the effect with a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Not without `setInterval`.

You could just have the code that applies an effect also note what changed.

You could do this with data attributes.

```
<div data-state="some state" ...

console.log(targetElement.getAttribute("data-state");
targetElement.setAttribute("data-state","changes");
MakeChanges(targetElement);
```

Comment: This is even more intensive than adding `console.log()` everywhere, but a valid approach nonetheless.

Comment: @Xeoncross - Intensive from a coding standpoint, or does this slow the execution down? Also, I only added `console.log` to show an entry point where you could monitor the previous state.

Comment: Intensive from DOM manipulation and coding. Having to add these checks and data-state attributes to each DOM element and at each function in the Javascript would mean thousands of lines of code for me.

Answer (score 1):

The following article introduces two techniques that might work in your case, Mutation Observers and Keyframes:

http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/

For each technique the article points to the related library.